# How to delete the git reference `refs/original/refs/heads/master`?

Tags: git, gitg

What's this in the yellow round box?

[image: screenshot]

I've tried `git branch -D`, `git tag -d` but none succeeded. So how to delete it?

Comment: Please consider changing the accepted answer to [Alexey Ten's answer](http://superuser.com/a/351085/101823) which is highly-upvoted, and correct (`git update-ref -d`).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[Alexey Ten has the better answer for this](https://superuser.com/a/351085/265) because it handles branches, tags, and packed refs. Future visitors should try that solution before this one.

---

If it's a tag, the following command ought to work:

```
git tag -d refs/original/refs/heads/master
```

But, since you've said it doesn't, you can just delete the file out of the `.git` directory. From the repository root, a command like this will get it:

```
rm .git/refs/tags/refs/original/refs/heads/master
```

The path may be slightly different if the `git-tag` command failed, so you may want to `cd .git/refs` and find the offending head by trial-and-error. Deleting the file will remove the reference from your local repository.

Comment: It's not a tag, however, I've found it  as `.git/refs/original/refs/heads/master`.

Comment: Use `git update-ref` rather than manually mutating Git's internals. See Alexey's answer.

Answer (score 129):

This command should work

```
git update-ref -d refs/original/refs/heads/master
```

Comment: This worked for me with the same problem. Note that the reference was stored in a file called .git/packed-refs. If you open that up you can see the line with the SHA and the string "refs/original/refs/heads/master". You could probably delete that line, but I'd use this command to be safe.

Comment: +1: You should *always* use `git update-ref -d` instead of just `rm`ing the ref - bad things can happen otherwise.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer

Comment: @CallumRogers why?

Comment: @wahnfrieden because git could use packed refs and there will be no corresponding file in `refs` directory

Comment: Oh, it's _that_ one out of the grab bag of nearly 200 Git subcommands with many more (inconsistent) command line switches  ...

Answer (score 23):

This is a ref. Normally created by `git filter-branch` - it is a pointer to where your branch was before you ran `git filter-branch`.

And to delete **any** ref, you can always push nothing to it in the local repository:

```
git push . :refs/original/refs/heads/master
```

The other answers also covered pretty well other ways of deleting.

Comment: "Pushing nothing" to delete the reference locally is very clever.

Comment: Made my day. I had a reference to a remote tag that the remote no longer existed. This is the only command that worked.

Comment: I was bashing my head against "error: dst refspec main matches more than one" because I had a `ref/head/main` and a `ref/heads/main` due to a typo.

Your answer saved my head.